# Ripple on tens-millivolts sinus waveform

Tags: noise, generator, dac, ripple, dds

I’m trying to make a DDS to generate a sinusoidal signal with tens to hundreds of millivolt amplitude and hundreds kHz frequency using an LTC1666 DAC. But I have some confusing results. Device schematic is in the picture below. As you can see, ripple is too strong. I found that NSD10-12D12 (the power supply) has a ripple voltage of 75mV maximum.

When I short oscilloscope probe with oscilloscope ground and short it to device GND I see huge ripple (see on a picture.) When I place probe on 50R output resistor I see signal with this ripple (how I think.)

In other case when I replace 50R resistor on output by oscilloscope 50R impedance input I found good signal. 
Can someone explain me how it can be, how to understand it, and where I have made a mistake?

Probe shorted with osciloscope GND. Noise is too small:

[image]

Probe shorted with oscilloscope GND and device GND, ripple is induced by the device ground and has a periodic structure:

[image: Probe shorted with oscilloscope GND and device GND]

Ripple superimposed on the output signal:

[image: Noised output]

On the picture below 50R output resistor replaced by 50R impedance osciloscope input. As you can see, in this case the signal is clear but I can’t understand how this happens:

[image: 50R output resistor replaced by 50R impedance osciloscope input]

Device schematic blocks:
[image: Device structure]

Comment: You need to be absolutely clearer on what each picture represents. At the moment it looks like a moan followed by an extract from a geeky photo album.

Comment: Probing is important especially with very low voltages (e.g. a few tens of millivolts as in your case) and high frequencies. If you use the alligator reference cable of the probe then it'll act as an antenna and pick some noise from outside world. That's why you see the noise in first two images. Please take a look at [here](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2016/07/27/how-you-measure-your-ripple-can-make-you-or-break-you) for better probing.